# There is no AWS Codedeploy Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-code-deploy

I use two different Jenkins servers(tomcat jenkins) and i was trying to install a plugin for aws codedeploy.

However, I couldn't find it in the list of a Jenkins but another one has it.

Why the plugin libraries are different? even though i install them in a same way.

Also, How can i add a particular plugin in my Jenkins server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the plugin libraries are different?

The plugin libraries shouldn't be different.
Which way did you search the plugin (jenkins gui, in the web)? Both your servers are on the same Jenkins version?

> Also, How can i add a particular plugin in my Jenkins server?

I do it always via the GUI as described here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It was my mistake..! Because i had already installed that plugin, i couldn't find it in the list of 'available'...
How silly i am.
Anyways, Thank you again. :)

Comment: no issue, was also once looking for a new plugin in my "Updates" list ;-)